# Messaging with two user tables in Laravel

Tags: laravel

I am developing a system in which it will have a chat system between two user tables: the clients and the engineers. My problem is how to make these two tables communicate in one message table with regard to registering the sender ID and recipient ID since both can change and are in different tables.

My initial thought for this was two tables where I would use the polymorphic relationship:

**chats**

```
id
client_id
engineer_id
```

**messages**

```
id
chat_id
senderable_id
senderable_type
receiverable_id
receiverable_type
content
```

What would be the most recommended way to solve this problem?

Comment: You problem is what the best way to model it?

Comment: Yes, I think this way won't work.

Comment: why would you think it wouldn't work?

Answer (score 0):

First of all, the following its the generic way  that I see to create a chat schem. It'll works to a chat with 2 users or more than 2 users.

Note, the `user_chat` table its the pivot table between `users` and `chats`. You can define an alias to that table, like "participants", because it what it means. You can add more attributes to `chats` table, but basically need to know the creator.

Finally, the secret in messages table is just to get the sender id from `users` table, because sender and receiver are relative concepts in this context.

[image]

Another more simple and reduced way to do it (if you are trying to make a chat with only 2 users) is:[image]